# How do I call line or cv::line with OpenCV 3.1?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1

The tutorial I'm following has code like the following:

```
line( img_matches, ..., ..., Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
```

where img_matches is just a Mat, the next two arguments are points and then there's a color and a width. I have figured out everything else that changed in OpenCV 3.1 for this tutorial but I cannot figure out how to draw lines. The documentation seems to imply it will simply be cv::line(...), but that is not defined in my namespace, and there's a cvLine in scope, but it is expecting something other than a Mat it seems like.

I'm no kind of C++ programmer, so this may be something basic.

As requested, here are my headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
```

My code is 99% what's in this tutorial here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

Comment: FWIW, I used what I believe is a C-ish approach by doing the following and it works: 1) assign img_matches to an IplImage pointer, 2) call cvLine using this temporary pointer instead of using img_matches. I would still like to know the C++ way.

Comment: what headers have you included?

Comment: Show your code, please

Comment: @slawekwin thanks for the pointer -- imgproc.hpp has what I need. Feel free to propose that as an answer and I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely you have not included the required header file.

Main header for opencv c++ api is in `opencv.hpp`, while the function you ask specifically (`cv::line`) is in `imgproc.hpp` (which is also included in most general `opencv.hpp`)

Comment: FWIW, in my version of OpenCV line is in imgproc.hpp, not core, so the old example code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @JamesWaldrop thanks, you are right - I checked in opencv 2.4 and (incorrectly) assumed it didn't change between versions